# sizeof on array returning different values

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this test program and it gives below output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
void fun(char arr[])
{
printf(".size of char : %d\n.", sizeof(arr[0]));
printf(".size of char array: %d\n.", sizeof(arr));
}

main()
{
char arr[10]={'a','b','c','d','e'};
fun(arr);

printf("size of char array: %d\n", sizeof(arr));
}
```

output

.size of char : 1
..size of char array: 8
.size of char array: 10

Now I understand that in first statement its size of member of array and in third statement is size of entire array but what does 8 in second printf says here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing the name of array decays to pointer to its first element. So `sizeof` is returning size of pointer which is 8 on your host system.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass an "array" to a function, you actually pass a pointer to the array. In other words, the expression `sizeof(array)` in `fun` returns the size of a pointer.

A common question in C and C++ is if you can find out the size of an array, given a pointer to it. Unfortunately, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the size of the pointer of the array, and not the array. When you pass an array to a function, the compiler maps the memory of the pointer to your array and passes it to the function. The array isn't passed. This returns the size "8".